# Returning column from instance using link_to and a simple AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a link that says "Show description" that when clicked appends the `description` column of the `Article` instance to the `.article__description--res` element in the view.

I have watched/read a few guides on this but can't find anything similar to what I'm trying to do. Everything uses forms / route members / partials etc.

How do I do this simple AJAX request?

```
# assets/javascripts/articles.js
$(function() {
  return $(".article__description--req").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    $('.article__description--res').append("<%= article.description %>"); # also tried <%= j article.description %>
  });
});

# views/articles/_article.html.erb
<div class="article__description">
  <%= link_to "Show description", article_path(article), remote: true, class: "article__description--req" %>
  <p class="article__description--res">
  </p>
</div>
```

---

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055630/5741622) I tried doing it this way but it didn't work.

```
# routes.rb
resources :articles do
  member do
    get "description", to: "articles#description"
  end
end

# articles_controller.rb
def description
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

# assets/javascripts/articles.js
$("a.article__description--req").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({url: "/articles/description", type: "GET", dataType: "script"});
}

# views/articles/_article.html.erb
<div class="article__info">
  <%= link_to "Show description", description_article_path(article), remote: true, class: "article__description--req" %>
  <p class="article__description--res">
  </p>
</div>

# views/articles/description.js.erb
$('.article__description--res').html('<%= escape_javascript(article.description) %>');
```

Comment: Try checking out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020554/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-load-content-from-a-database-via-a-ruby-on-rails-action. I think you should use jQuery#on method and identify the click of the link

Comment: @philipyoo I will read that, thank you.

Comment: @philipyoo I'm having trouble relating it to what I'm trying to do. Edited my post with my attempt

Comment: Sorry, let me try and make a post

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions. You're viewing a list of all articles, by lets say the article title. When you click on the title, the article description displays.

I'm not exactly sure on the specifics, but I want to show you generally how I'd do something like this.

```
# articles_controller.rb
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @articles }
  end
end

# assets/javascripts/articles.js
$('#article-container').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get('/articles').success(function(data) {
    var parsed_data = // parse `data` here
    $('.article__description--res').html(parsed_data);
  })
}
```

I imagine you're gonna want to parse the data based on the article `id` selected. Also, another problem that might arise is determining and showing the correct article description. These specifics I'm not sure of, and honestly I'd just mess around with it once you get the json data you want, and determine how to parse it and display it.

Comment: Sorry I should've given more information. I'm doing this in `_article.html.erb`, displaying them in the index of a category (`Category has_many :articles`). Omitted the nested stuff for brevity. I'll play around with what you've given me here and see if I can figure it out.